# redux-oidc redirect from keycloak - USER_EXPIRED called just before USER_FOUND, causing flashing login screen

Tags: react-redux, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, redux-oidc

I have a login system using [redux-oidc](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc), with [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) as the ID manager.  The app's landing page is the login screen.  When the user clicks the login button, they are directed to sign in with keycloak. On sign in, they are redirected back to our app.  The issue is the login screen is flashing momentarily before they are brought to the app.  We are trying to get rid of that.  Here are the redux actions fired once the page loads from the redirect:

[image]

I can see right here why the login screen is flashing - `LOADING_USER` sets `state.oidc.isLoadingUser` to true, but `USER_EXPIRED` sets it to false.  Then `USER_FOUND` sets the user, and our `LOGIN_SUCCESS` keeps all the user / session data in the store and calls `state.auth.authenticated` true.  On page load from redirect, there is a brief moment where I have no user data and no auth, and no way of knowing that the oidc client is still in process of loading my user.

This is *not* the case on page reload once already signed in.  On reload, I get this:

[image]

This makes sense, as the user data is already there, so either `state.oidc.isLoadingUser` or `state.oidc.user` is true.  But I would expect this to be the same on first page load from redirect, as the user data is sent with the `redirect_uri`.  Taking a look at the code, we call `redux-oidc`'s `loadUser` right after the store is defined:

```js
// in index.js 
const store = createStore(rootReducer, middleware)
loadUser(store, userManager);
```

We are setting up the `userManager` in a pretty standard way as far as I can tell:

```js
const userManagerConfig = {
  authority: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}:8081/auth/realms/master`,
  client_id: "myclientid",
  redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${
    window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ""
  }${window.location.pathname}`,
  response_type: "code",
  scope: "openid",
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 20,
  revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
  post_logout_redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${
    window.location.hostname
  }${window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ""}`
};
```

The callback component is the `LoginPage` itself:

```js
// LoginScreen.tsx

<CallbackComponent userManager={userManager} >
  <div>
    <h3>Log me in Scotty</h3>
    <Button onClick={() => { userManager.signinRedirect()} } >
      Login
    </Button>
  </div>
</CallbackComponent>
```

And within the app, we only render the routes if the user is `authenticated`.  Otherwise, we render the login screen:

```js
// App.tsx
const App = () => {

   if (authenticated) {
     return (
       <Authenticated_App_With_All_The_Routes />
     );
   }
   return <LoginPage />;

}
```

The connection between oidc and `authenticated` lives in our sagas, where `USER_FOUND` is intercepted, and we call a subsequent action to pass the payload to the store and set `authenticated` to true.

Perhaps this was TMI, but I want to give the full scope of the issue.  I believe the core of it is that for some reason, redux-oidc is calling `USER_EXPIRED` and *then* calling `USER_FOUND` once keycloak redirect back to our app.  Why?  How can I keep track on page load of the fact that we are still waiting for redux-oidc to find the user?  I need to let my app (and users) know that you just logged in through a third party, hang on a sec while we redirect you to the app.  I am new to OIDC so forgive me if I'm missing some glaring issue.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, how did you solve this?

Comment: I did indeed solve it, I'll post an answer in a few minutes here

Answer (score 2):

As per request, I'll answer my own question.  I was never able to avoid the fact that `USER_EXPIRED` fires before `USER_FOUND` when logging in.  However, once you log in from the OIDC and are redirected back to the application, the URL is now appended with `/redirect?state=some_state_token&session_state=session_state_token&etc=etc`.

I am using react router and I tapped into the fact that I can render different components based on the url.  Where I was rendering my `App` actually involved a `<Switch>` block, like  so:

```js
// App.tsx
const App = () => {

   if (authenticated) {
     return (
       <Authenticated_App_With_All_The_Routes />
     );
   }
   return (
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/redirect">
         <LoginScreen redirect />
       </Route>
       <Route path="/">
         <LoginScreen />
       </Route>
     </Switch>
   )
}
```

So when the user arrives at the home screen, they get the regular `LoginPage`.  When they login in and are redirected back from the OIDC, they actually get the login page with the `redirect` prop, which will actually render the login page, but instead of a login button, it gives a "Redirecting . . ." message:

```js
// LoginScreen.tsx
const LoginScreen = ({ redirect }) => {

  if (!authenticated){
    return (
      <CallbackComponent userManager={userManager} >
        <div>
          {redirect && <div>Redirecting . . .</div>}
          {!redirect && <h3>Log me in Scotty</h3>
          <Button onClick={() => { userManager.signinRedirect()} } >
            Login
          </Button>}
        </div>
      </CallbackComponent>
    )
  }

  return <Redirect to="/" />

}
```

So once we get rerouted back, we see the "Redirecting . . ." message for a moment, until `LOGIN_SUCCESS` fires, changes `authenticated` to true, and the LoginScreen redirects the app to the homepage.  I think this is perfectly fine for UX, as we need to show something that makes sense for the brief moment that the OIDC is doing the redirect. This seems to be consistent with best practices and alot of enterprise-level OIDC UX.

#### Extra credit: routing back to the page you were on

We had a requirement that if the user got logged out from inactivity, they would be sent back to the login screen, but they'd still be on the url they were on (for example, they'd be on `app.com/subsection`, but logged out, they'd see the login screen.  From there, clicking on login screen bumps them over the the oidc.  In the redux-oidc `userManagerConfig`:

```js
redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${
    window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ""
  }/redirect${
    window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]
      ? `?from=${window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]}`
      : ""
  }`
```

What this does is that if they are on some subroute when trying to log in, a `?from=subroute` param is added to the redirect uri.  Then in the login redirect:

```js
  return (
    <Redirect
      to={`/${new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("from") || ""}`}
    />
  );
```

The OIDC remembers where they were, passes it as part of the `to` prop in the route, and the user ends up logged in and back on the page where they were before.  This particular example only accounts for the first subpath (between the first two `/`), but this can be customized to get you back to where you were entirely - may be tricky if you app is using deep linking.  You also have to be careful that any 404 pages aren't caught in the `/redirect` routes.